# Positioning a CSS button to the top-right in a fieldset

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-position

```
.bot {
  background-color: sky-blue;
  position: absolute;
  line-height: 22px;
  width: 78px;
  margin-top: 25px;
  margin-right: 35px;
  top: 0px;
  right: 0px; 
}
```

How do I position my clickable button to remain at the top-right inside a `<fieldset>`? With this my code, the button hangs outside the `<fieldset>`.

Comment: Hey Michy and welcome to SO. You're using `pixel` as a unit but that should be written as `px`. There is no longhand version of `px`, so your CSS lines are invalid and therefor won't be rendered. Change it and see it will work.

Comment: `0 pixel` or `18 pixel` are not valid . `0`on its own is plenty enough and for a pixel value it is `18px` . I'm curious to know where you got this idea from (or leaned this that way from ) ;)

Comment: I highly suggest working your way through the MDN free classes on CSS. This will help you hone your css skills writing valid css to style your HTML.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS happy coding

Comment: I have taken corrections and made all changes. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Try making fieldset as position relative like this below

```
fieldset {
  position:relative;
}
```